# Remove stargazer column from table

Tags: r, stargazer, nnet

I want to make a table of a multinomial logit model with `{stargazer}`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(nnet)

# create sample data
data <- tibble(
  choice = rep(c("strawberry", "mango", "orange"), 100),
  likes_kiwi = rbinom(300, size = 1, prob = 0.3),
  inner_beauty = rnorm(n = 300, mean = 5, sd = 2)
)

# set reference level to strawberry
data_ref_s <- data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(choice), function(x) as.factor(x) %>% relevel(., ref = "strawberry"))

# set reference level to mango
data_ref_m <- data %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(choice), function(x) as.factor(x) %>% relevel(., ref = "mango"))

m1 <- multinom(choice ~ likes_kiwi + inner_beauty, data = data_ref_s)
#> # weights:  12 (6 variable)
#> initial  value 329.583687 
#> iter  10 value 328.812148
#> iter  10 value 328.812148
#> iter  10 value 328.812148
#> final  value 328.812148 
#> converged
m2 <- multinom(choice ~ likes_kiwi + inner_beauty, data = data_ref_m)
#> # weights:  12 (6 variable)
#> initial  value 329.583687 
#> iter  10 value 328.812148
#> iter  10 value 328.812148
#> iter  10 value 328.812148
#> final  value 328.812148 
#> converged

library(stargazer)
#> 
#> Please cite as:
#>  Hlavac, Marek (2018). stargazer: Well-Formatted Regression and Summary Statistics Tables.
#>  R package version 5.2.2. https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=stargazer

stargazer(
  m1, m2, type = "text", 
  column.labels = c("strawberry vs. mango", "strawberry vs. orange", "mango vs. orange", "mango vs. strawberry")
  )
#> 
#> ==================================================================================================
#>                                                 Dependent variable:                               
#>                   --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#>                          mango                         orange                      strawberry     
#>                   strawberry vs. mango strawberry vs. orange mango vs. orange mango vs. strawberry
#>                           (1)                   (2)                (3)                (4)         
#> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> likes_kiwi               -0.143                0.133              0.276              0.143        
#>                         (0.311)               (0.302)            (0.307)            (0.311)       
#>                                                                                                   
#> inner_beauty             0.016                -0.044              -0.060             -0.016       
#>                         (0.074)               (0.074)            (0.074)            (0.074)       
#>                                                                                                   
#> Constant                 -0.040                0.175              0.215              0.040        
#>                         (0.415)               (0.409)            (0.411)            (0.415)       
#>                                                                                                   
#> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#> Akaike Inf. Crit.       669.624               669.624            669.624            669.624       
#> ==================================================================================================
#> Note:                                                                  *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

<sup>Created on 2020-06-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

How can I remove the output from column (4) (equivalent to the output in column (1) with only the covariate signs reversed) using the stargazer options?

FYI: I included the models twice in the example above with different reference levels (`data_ref_m`, `data_ref_s`), such as to get to the table structure I wish for.